# How to mount an AES-encrypted .DMG file containing a FAT12 filesystem?

Tags: mount, encryption

My question says it all: on Ubuntu, is there any way to mount a .dmg file (as produced by OS X's Disk Utility) that contains an AES-encrypted, FAT12 filesystem?

I've seen sporadic advice about how to mount .dmg files containing hfsplus filesystems, so I'd have thought the fat12 (aka, "msdos") filesystem would be even easier. The closest I've come is:

```
mount -oloop,encryption=aes-256 -t msdos privatedmg.dmg ~/mounted
```

But this gives me the error `ioctl: LOOP_SET_STATUS: Invalid argument`. I don't know much about linux filesystem mechanics, but am eager to learn!

Comment: mount does not support ~/mounted expansion i guess.
try /home/YourName/mounted.

Comment: Thanks @LiYong, but using an absolute path gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

emm what's coming to my mind I can help you this way only:

If it's possible or if you're willing converting `.dmg` to `.img hfsplus` open a Terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install dmg2img
```

then install mountable manager, I use AcetoneISO:

```
sudo apt-get install acetoneiso
```

or Mountmanager:

```
sudo apt-get install mountmanager
```

firstly try to mount `.dmg` using one of these packages, if no access you can still use converting tool mentioned above.